# How to Force Python 3 to Output String Using Single Quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When preparing insert queries for PostgreSQL table, Postgres does not accept double quotes to surround values. As an example `burja duba''i` supposed to be outputted (written to a file) as **'**`burja duba''i`**'**, however, because there are single quotes within `burja duba''i`, Python 3 outputs `"burja duba''i"`. How to get the desired format: `'burja duba''i'`?

P.S. I'd rather preparing the statement separately and then running them than using psycopg2.

---

Attempts to solve it:

```
>>> a = "burja duba''i"
>>> b = a.split("''")
>>> b[0] + "''" + b[1]
"burja duba''i"
# still same as a
```

Stoopid I know but I'm stuck

Comment: Why not `a = "'burja duba''i'"`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. How is "Python outputs strings with double quotes when you print them" related to "Postgres does not accept double quotes"? The way Python prepares data for stdout should have no bearing on data Postgres recieves, because Python doesn't send data to Postgres via stdout unless you're doing something very strange. Can you share the code where you actually run the statement?

Comment: @zwer because > Postgres does not accept double quotes to surround values.

Comment: @Kevin The statements is being written to a file. Python/PostgeSQL relation is not for context.

Comment: @ms2r - Double quotes are there to just define a string value in Python - once printed to `STDOUT` or written to a file it won't have double quotes around it.

Comment: I feel like there are much easier ways to execute a db query than by writing the query to a file. If you simply executed the query directly, then all of these quote-related problems would completely vanish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use escaped characters -

```
a = "burja duba''i"
b = a.split("''")
print('\'' + b[0] + '\'\'' + b[1] + '\'')
```

OUTPUT

```
'burja duba''i'
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to bound your string in single quotes you can use this code.

```
a = 'burja duba \'\'i
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to surround your string with single quotes, try using the following:

```
>>> a = "burja duba''i"
>>> b = a.split("''")
>>> "'%s ''%s'" % (b[0], b[1])
'burja duba''i'
```

I opt to use `%` because it's faster than the alternative `.format`.

Other alternatives are to escape the character etc. - Although I wouldn't go down that route, keep it clean.

Comment: Last line is `"'burja duba ''i'"`